# PySpark Join based on case statement

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to join two dataFrame based on a SQL case statement like the one below. Please tell me what is the best approach to deal with this situation?

```
from df1 
     left join df2 d 
      on d."Date1" <= Case when v."DATE2" >= v."DATE3" then df1."col1" else df1."col2" end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would put it into a UDF which returns a boolean value. Therefore the business logic will end up in the Python code and the SQL will stay clean:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType

>>> def join_based_on_dates(left_date, date0, date1, col0, col1):
>>>     if(date0 >= date1):
>>>         right_date = col0
>>>     else:
>>>         right_date = col1
>>>     return left_date <= right_date

>>> sqlContext.registerFunction("join_based_on_dates", join_based_on_dates, BooleanType())

>>> join_based_on_dates("2016-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2018-01-01", "res1", "res2");
True

>>> sqlContext.sql("SELECT join_based_on_dates('2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2018-01-01', 'res1', 'res2')").collect();
[Row(_c0=True)]
```

Your query will end up something like:

```
FROM df1
LEFT JOIN df2 ON join_based_on_dates('2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2018-01-01', 'res1', 'res2')
```

Hope this helps, have fun with Spark!